# Why don't code snippets work in Tag Wikis?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-wiki, stack-snippets

I noticed code snippets don't work in tag wikis. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info

My reasoning for asking:

- In most front end tags there will be examples of the relevant code.
  Snippets would be useful in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [html](/questions/tagged/html) [css](/questions/tagged/css)
  [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas) and the list goes on.
- This feature would be neither damaging nor useful to tags that don't 
  involve client-side technologies.
- Stack Overflow (and other sites that have stack snippets enabled) appear to use the same markdown editor/display for tag wikis as for questions and answers.

Comment: To Close Voters: Stack Snippets is a feature that is not limited to only Stack Overflow. The question uses that site as an example. As such this is applicable to more then one site and therefor this question shouldn't be closed for that reason.

Comment: What I noticed is that in the preview it looks like regular code, but in the actual wiki it is inside a box like a snippet, although any controls are nowhere to be found.